# Calling BAT with VBA - CMD Loads and Closes Immediately

Tags: excel, cmd, plink, vba

I'm using VBA to write a command file and a BAT file which calls PLink to log in to a server and run a script. The Plink portion is now functioning as expected thanks to some help on here. Unfortunately VBA seems to be having some difficulty with opening the cmd and finding plink as a usable command.

I've tried multiple different ways of calling it, but the results are all the same. The cmd prompt opens and then closes immediately giving me an error stating:

```
"plink is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file."
```

The files generate perfectly, and if I run the bat file outside of VBA, it runs as expected. With the files, I keep a copy of plink.exe on the desktop. I've even tried adding a copy of cmd.exe to the desktop with the links and plink.exe as well, but I get the same problem.

Here are some of the ways I've tried, though modified for my code: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380923/executing-batch-file-in-vba-using-shell-commend-is-not-working)  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403341/running-a-batch-file-in-a-given-directory-using-vba)  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530371/execute-bat-file-from-excel-vba-macro)

Here's the most recent code for the macro:

```
Dim vPath As String
Dim vscript As String

UserID = Range("F1").Value
Passwd = Range("F2").Value
Server = Range("F3").Value
StartDate = Range("F4").Value
EndDate = Range("F5").Value

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CopyFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe", "C:\Users\MikeDesktop\"
'fso.CopyFile "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe", "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\"

vPath = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop"
Open vPath & "\pcmd.txt " For Output As #1
Print #1, "cd /opt/test/srt"
Print #1, "./srt.tool " & StartDate & " " & EndDate & " > /opt/test/srt/test.txt &"
Print #1, "rm test.txt"
Print #1, "sleep 60; exit"
Close #1

Open vPath & "\Chg.bat" For Output As #1
Print #1, "plink " & UserID & "@" & Server & " -pw " & Passwd & " < " & vPath & "\pcmd.txt"
Close #1
vscript = vPath & "\Chg.bat"

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 5

wsh.Run vscript, windowStyle, waitOnReturn

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
Kill vPath & "\Chg.bat"
Kill vPath & "\pcmd.txt"
Kill vPath & "\plink.exe"
```

If someone can tell me why the cmd isn't recognizing plink as an option, that would be much appreciated

Comment: have you tried including the full path to `plink`, instead of relying on it being on the `%Path%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass the path to plink.exe in the batch file, or make sure that %Path% includes the folder that contains plink.exe.

Comment: Adding the path into the batch file fixed it. Odd that it still worked when I just double clicked the BAT file outside of the macro, but it wouldn't work in the macro without it. Thanks!